# HERE API api key not working with trusted domains?

Tags: here-api

I'm trying to embed an image from the HERE Map Image API on a website. I've created an API key and it all works fine. However, I want to secure that API key by enabling "Trusted Domains" in the Access Manager on the HERE platform. But it stops working when I activate the "Trusted Domains". Everything works fine again after deactivating the feature.

What am I doing wrong? Am I missing something? Here's the image tag I'm using, and I can assure the test domain is correctly added to the list of trusted domains.

```
<img alt="" src="https://image.maps.ls.hereapi.com/mia/1.6/mapview?apiKey=xyz&c=40.6893078,-74.0461798&sb=mk&t=1&z=19&w=640&h=480&nodot" />
```

The error is:

```
{"error":"Unauthorized","error_description":"apiKey invalid. apiKey not found."}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you pass `Referer` header which contains the domain as a header value then it would work

Comment: Thanks, but how should I set a header in an <img> tag? I've tried `referrerpolicy="origin"`, but it doesn't work either.

Comment: Right, it's embedded. Then the browser should send a Referer header with embedded image requests.

Comment: Hi @belomat, unfortunately the service is not supporting trusted domain at this moment. It will be enabled by mid Aug.